# Form Fields Validation Through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a form and i want when the fields are empty the border of the fields gets red but my code is not working please help ! i'm using bootstrap and jquery framework

MY JQUERY

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $("#form").submit(function() {

        var username = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confPassword = $("#confPassword").val();
        var message = $("#warning");

        if (username == "" && email == "" && password == "" && confPassword == "") {
            return false;
            $("#username").css("border", "1px solid red");
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: check the solution also helps you..to write good code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` after setting the css rule. Once the `return` statement is executed none of the statement after it in the function is executed because the control flow is returned to the caller by the `return` call.

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    $("#form").submit(function () {

        var username = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confPassword = $("#confPassword").val();
        var message = $("#warning");

        if (username == "" && email == "" && password == "" && confPassword == "") {
            $("#username").css("border", "1px solid red");
            return false;//return after setting the properties
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **OR** `||` to check if user has entered text.

```
if (username == "" || email == "" || password == "" || confPassword == "" || password != confPassword) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to avoe answer try code so you should not have to write line of code for each text box,

```
var isvalid = true;
$("#username, #email, #password, #confPassword, #warning").each(
function()
{
  if($(this).val()==="")
  {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
   isvalid = false;
  }
}
);
return isvalid;
```